# What's the difference between using DEFAULT and not using it to create a database with collation in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to SQl and I want to know how to create a database with collation, by searching in google I found two syntaxes, and I want to know the difference between them?

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

#### Reference

[Using Default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html)

[Not Using Default](https://www.euperia.com/development/mysql-create-database-with-utf8-character-set-syntax/1064)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference between the two. `DEFAULT` is an optional keyword. Both set the collation on the database, and specify a default for tables created in the database. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-database.html